# How to make the header transparent in the background video?

Tags: html, css

I spent a lot of time solving this problem and still don't understand what I am doing wrong. I need my title to be transparent with no background. As an example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cV4D.jpg)

But I don't understand how transparency works, I tried everything I could, but it is always white and transparency only applies to text. I have a video playing in the background. I found solutions where I need to insert an image, but this does not help me, since I have a video in the background, not a picture.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.section {
  padding: 0 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

.intro {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: url("cover.jpg") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.intro:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.intro__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.intro__title {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 72px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 84px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.i_title {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}


}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  zoom: 0.4;
}
.video__media {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
 <section>
      <div class="box">
        <p>Here is some more content of the header...</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="intro">
      <div class="video">
        <video class="video__media" src="media/video.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
      </div>

      <div class="intro__content">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="intro__title">None</h1>
          <h1 class="i_title">None</h1>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello, do you need the whole header to be invisible or just text inside it??

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times